# Не получается изменить цвет пришельцев из yellow в red. Код прилагается! Я пока только учусь, не судите строго

Tags: python, python-3.8

````
# Создание пустого списка для хранения пришельцев.
aliens = []
# Создание 30 зеленых пришельцев.
for alien_number in range(30):
    new_alien = {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
    aliens.append(new_alien) 
for alien in aliens[0:5]:
    if alien['color'] == 'green':
        alien['color'] = 'yellow'
        alien['speed'] = 'medium'
        alien['points'] = 10 ``` 
--->  elif alien['color'] == 'yellow':
        alien['color'] = 'red'
        alien['speed'] = 'fast'
        alien['points'] = 15  <---
 # Вывод первых 5 пришельцев:
 for alien in aliens[:15]:
     print(alien)
 print('...')
 # Вывод количества созданных пришельцев.
 print("Total number of aliens: " + str(len(aliens)))
````

Comment: Что означает "не получается"?

Comment: Отступы поправьте

Comment: отступы менял, но он выдает ошибку.

Comment: @Mr.Robot выдает ошибку - надо читать ошибку. Ошибки для того и выдаются.

Comment: Ясно, неуместные коментарии человека, который никак и ничто не понимает!

Comment: @Mr.Robot всё он понимает. Добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос, давайте вместе его прочитаем.

Comment: Cof. Cof. уже помог

Comment: @Mr.Robot ага, не хватает ума прочитать ошибку у тебя, а не понимаю отчего-то я  неуместные реплики человека, которые полный ноль в том, чем делает вид, что занимается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из кода красных пришельцев быть и не должно, т.к а)elif не позволяет жёлтому пришельцу перейти в красного(заменить на if); б)Жёлтые и зелёные пришельцы больше нигде не используются.
Я не могу дать более точных корректировок из-за недостатка информации, т.к я к сожалению даже не знаю с какой целью писался код.
P.S Мои привилегии на форуме не позволяют оставить это в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Пример задачки из книги Мэтиза "Изучаем питон", практически полностью повторяющийся в книге, там сказано что с добавлением elif, цитирую: "Цикл можно расширить, добавив блок elif для превращения желтых пришельцев
в красных — быстрых и приносящих игроку по 15 очков." На деле этот фрагмент кода как раз не работает, как задумано, поскольку elif срабатывает только, если первичное условие if не выполнилось, а оно как раз таки выполнилось и выдало true и миновало оставшуюся часть условного блока. Я новичок в изучении Питона, но могу заверить, что этот код не вызовет ошибки, но не решит поставленное условие. Поэтому исправьте меня, если я считаю, что переделать пришельцев в красный тип после жёлтого можно лишь добавив в конце блока if alien['color']='green':......
другой блок if:
...if alien['color']='yellow':
alien['color']='red'...
По крайней мере это работает. Профессионалы, подскажите, можно ли решить этот пример элегантнее?